# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Getting error with code

> WHERE `client_id` LIKE '23' Notice: Undefined variable: check1_res in
>   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/.../public/client/billing/service.php on
>   line 68 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'WHERE `client_id` LIKE '23'' at line 1

with code

```
$search=checkRequest('search');
$type=checkRequest('type');
$search_key=checkRequest('term');

if($search == 'id'){
    $mysearch = "WHERE `client_id` LIKE '$search_key'";
}elseif($search == 'tech'){

}else{
    //$where = "`id` LIKE '$search_key'";

}
echo $mysearch;
$service_lookup = "SELECT * FROM `$billingdb`.`service` ORDER BY entry_date_u $mysearch";
$service = $conn->query($service_lookup);
```

I have tried and it works the echo of the search in phpmyadmin and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

The order of your query is wrong.

**Solution:** `WHERE` should come before `ORDER BY`:

```
$service_lookup = "SELECT * FROM `$billingdb`.`service` $mysearch ORDER BY entry_date_u";
```

The order is:

```
SELECT..
FROM...
WHERE...
GROUP BY...
HAVING...
ORDER BY...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause comes before the `order by` clause. So instead of

```
$service_lookup = "SELECT * FROM `$billingdb`.`service` ORDER BY entry_date_u $mysearch";
```

You should have

```
$service_lookup = "SELECT * FROM `$billingdb`.`service` $mysearch ORDER BY entry_date_u";
```

Answer (score 0):

You syntax is wrong. `Order by`must be after where so you have to use:

```
$service_lookup = "SELECT * FROM `$billingdb`.`service` $mysearch ORDER BY entry_date_u ";
```

For more information about the SQL SELECT syntax see the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Also you should learn about prepared statement.